# UWP exclude "Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException" exceptions for the WebView control

Tags: javascript, exception, webview, uwp

I have a UWP app with a WebView control.  The app works fine however the Visual Studio 2017 output window shows a bunch of errors such as:

```
Exception thrown at 0x75ECB832 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException at memory location 0x071FE1BC.
Exception thrown at 0x75ECB832 in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException at memory location 0x071FD83C.
etc...
```

The errors occur for instance on web pages such as http://www.google.com, even if I unmark all the exceptions from the "Exception Settings" window.
I could just ignore the exceptions, since they are probably minor javascript runtime errors, but they are also slowing down the debugger quite a bit.

Any advice on how to hide these exceptions from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check Debug tab in your project properties - what `Debugger type` you have there? If it's Native Only or Mixed, try to switch to Managed Only. Btw,  if you switch to Script, Visual Studio will break at exact place where JS error is happening in the script.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  There is probably a reason why these exceptions cannot be excluded directly from the Output window, but that's probably a different topic...  Also, it's scary to see that 99% of all web sites generate some kind of Javascript exceptions (at least from the WebView control).

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, I work with WebView too and see tons of errors as well. Well, as long as websites work, I guess :)